# How can I fadeIn() first then fadeOut() then insertAfter()?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fade

I have simple div fade cycle made. Some divs are in a outer div and that is in another outer div. I have a script written that cycles those divs by fading in and out. But there's a problem, the divs are faden out but are faden in.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeE9x/1/) and see that ugly effect.

**JS:**

```
function tick() {
    var $obj = $(".major_data .commitment_box .commitment");
    $obj.first().fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut(function () {
        $obj.first().insertAfter($obj.last());
        tick();
    });
}
tick();
```

When a the cycle repeats itself then the effect becomes right. How can I achieve the effect in the second cycle of the cycle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"But there's a problem, the divs are faden out but are faden in."*

I assume you're trying to say that "the divs are *not* faded out" to begin with. If you're saying that you want the divs to all start out hidden so that then even the first one fades in just change the following line:

```
var $obj = $(".major_data .commitment_box .commitment");
```

...to this:

```
var $obj = $(".major_data .commitment_box .commitment").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function tick() {
        var $obj = $(".major_data .commitment_box .commitment").hide();
        $obj.first().fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(function () {
            $obj.first().insertAfter($obj.last());
            tick();
        });
    }
    tick();
```

Use `.fadeIn(1000)` to avoid fading in immediately

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jeE9x/2/)

Or

```
function tick() {
    var $obj = $(".major_data .commitment_box .commitment").hide();
    $obj.first().fadeIn(1000,function () {
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $obj.first().insertAfter($obj.last());
        tick();
    });
}
tick();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jeE9x/3/)

Answer (score 0):

All you `.commitment` divs are already visisble when you first cycle trought them, so there is nothing for jQuery to `fadeIn`. The second round, they are hidden cause of the previous `fadeOut`, so the `fadeIn` does work this time.

The solution would be to initially hide your .`commitment` divs. I would do this by adding `.commitment {  display: none; }` to your css.